# jQuery isotope initialize with filtered results

Tags: jquery, jquery-isotope

Hi I'm using jQuery Isotope and I have a filter like this:

```
<ul class="filter option-set " data-filter-group="date">        
   <li><a class="selected" href="#filter-date-January" data-filter-value=".January">January</a></li>
   <li><a href="#filter-date-April" data-filter-value=".April" class="">April</a></li>
   <li><a href="#filter-date-any" data-filter-value="" class="">ALL</a></li>
 </ul>
```

Even though I use the "selected" class for the first item, the items are not filtered by that criteria, it shows all instead.
Is there anything else I should do to make it work?

Thanks in advance.
Lu

Answer (score 0, accepted):

You could split initialization and filtering. 
I'd prefer to handle filtering in a separate function, i.e:

```
$(function() {
   // isotope init
   $(container).isotope({
       itemSelector: '.item',
       animationOptions: {
           duration: 750,
           easing: 'linear',
           queue: false
       }
   });

   filterItems(); // filter onload

});

var selectedDate = '.January'; // update this var with your UI

var filterItems = function() {
    $('ul.option-set li a').each(function(i, a) {
        if($(a).data('filter-value') == selectedDate) {
            $(a).addClass('selected');
        }
        else {
            $(a).removeClass('selected');
        }
    }); 
   $container.isotope({
        filter: '.selected',
        isAnimate: true
    });
};
```

Comment: Thanks for your answer. How can I use this for combined filters? I'm filter by date and by type.

Comment: Great! Thanks. I changed the function to add the selected class to the items instead of the filters and it worked.